# LabVIEW Report Generation Toolkit cannot find Microsoft Word

Tags: labview

I am trying to create a new **word** report an get the following:

```
Error -41106 occurred at NI_Word.lvclass:new report subVI.vi -> NI_report.lvclass:New Report.vi

Possible reason(s):

Report Generation Toolkit: Microsoft Word or Excel did not open. Make sure Microsoft Word or Excel is installed.
```

It works fine when run as **standard report** so the Report Generation Toolkit is installed.

I have licensed microsoft excel 2013 and microsoft word 2013 both installed on my PC.  Any ideas why it is failing to open?

Comment: Just came across this : https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P82QSAS